# iPad body size css issues

Tags: javascript, css, ipad, styles, orientation

this is a website I just created. http://www.imageworkz.asia/TheHatLab

the problem is that when it is viewed in the iPad. Even if the body's width and height were set to 1024 x 768 in the stylesheet, it has an excess background of the body (the black one) on the right side if it is on landscape orientation and on the right side and bottom side if it is on portrait orientation.

Any ideas?

Comment: In landscape mode, the screen is 1024x768 but the top bar of the browser takes up some of that space.  To fit your page in the remaining space (vertically), its size is decreased, which solves one problem but creates another (the excess background on the right side).

Answer (score 2):

Have you investigated viewport?

eg:    `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried preventing page zoom? http://davidwalsh.name/zoom-mobile-browsers
Or have you tried implementing a viewport http://www.allenpike.com/2010/choosing-a-viewport-for-ipad-sites/

Answer (score 0):

You have given the size 1024x766 to the body. Give size to the container not into body. It worked for me. May be due to view port sizing involves html & body elements.

[image: iPad simulator screenshot]

Comment: body {
 
 margin:0 auto;
 color:#aca194;
 background:black;
}
#container {
 width:1024px;
 height:768px;
 background:white;
} did what u said and still not working :((

Comment: opps!! that's  weird. Check by adding this 

<meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="height=device-height,width=device-width,user-scalable=no" />

Comment: did that as well...still not working...this is very odd. My first layout worked fine -> http://www.imageworkz.asia/TheHatLab2

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the address bar ([you can find lots of information on this](https://www.google.com/search?q=mobile%20safari%20hide%20browse)) or you can reduce the size of your content to the space remaining (or you can do a layout that adjusts to fill the available space).